# How to know the summary of the distance with ends_with selection

Tags: r, dplyr

im trying to get the summary of the distance with the flights ends with INC text

so i did join two database to get names

```
flights <- left_join(flights, airlines, by="carrier")
```

than i used function:

```
> flights %>% select(name, ends_with("Inc.")) %>% summarise(dist=sum(flights$distance))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
       dist
      <dbl>
1 350217607
```

and also tried:

```
> flights %>% filter(name, ends_with("Inc.")) %>% summarise(dist=sum(flights$distance))
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

But in first case its simply making summary of all airlines not the one i specified shall be finished with "Inc." 
second trial simply says mistake etc...
what am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: can you post a reproducible example and add expected output as well?

Comment: what do you mean by reproducible example? its dataset from nycflights13 (flights and airlines) the output im looking for is the summary of distance of the flights that includes in their name last 3 letters "Inc". please let me know if needed more clarification. thank you!

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was from that dataset. I have added few options to get the answer below, see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have an idea why my code was summarizing all the data even if i used pipeline and specified that i want to select specific text? forgot to add, your answers were very helpful! thank you for your time!

Comment: 1) You were using `$` in the pipes. Using `$` removes all the grouping filtering operations. 2) `select` is used to filter columns and not rows. 3) `ends_with` is used to select columns by their names and not filter the rows.

Comment: Thank you so much for such clear answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyvverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
flights %>%
     filter(str_detect(name, "Inc\\.$")) %>%
      summarise(dist = sum(distance))
```

---

If we use `ends_with` with `select` statement, it checks the column names and select the matching column.  Here, the OP wants to select rows.  So, the pattern should be used with `filter` on the selected column name

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in multiple ways, some of them as shown below

```
library(dplyr)
flights %>% filter(grepl("Inc.$", name)) %>% summarise(dist = sum(distance))

#       dist
#      <dbl>
#1 249500641

flights %>%  summarise(dist = sum(distance[grepl("Inc.$", name)]))

flights %>% slice(grep("Inc.$", name)) %>% summarise(dist = sum(distance))
```

Or using base R

```
sum(with(flights, distance[endsWith(name, "Inc.")]))
#[1] 249500641

sum(with(flights, distance[grepl("Inc.$", name)]))

sum(with(flights, distance[grep("Inc.$", name)]))
```

Also a side note, Never use `$` in pipes more often than not it will mess up the calculation.